# Spring Custom Converter - To Bean or Not to Bean

Tags: java, spring

I am implementing Custom Converter in Spring so my beans can convert from `java.util.Date` to `java.time.LocalDateTime`. I have implemented Converter already (by implementing Spring `Converter` interface)

Here is bean definition in `@Configuration` class

```
   @Bean
   ConversionService conversionService(){
      DefaultConversionService service = new DefaultConversionService();
      service.addConverter(new DateToLocalDateTimeConverter());
      return service;
    }
```

My question is : shall I pass my custom converter as Java Object or Spring Bean to `service.addConverter`? 
In general what are the guidelines (criterias) whether to bean or not to bean in such scenarios?

Comment: If you are already using Spring, I see no benefits of not using its beans

Comment: @IvanPronin No benefits of not to bean, but disadvantage is overhead of Spring Bean instantiation. Don't you think it is superfluous in this case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Making an object a Spring Bean makes sense as you want that this object may benefit from Spring features (injections, transaction, aop, etc...).

In your case, it seems not required.
As `conversionService` is a Spring bean singleton that will be instantiated once, creating during its instantiation a plain java instance of `DateToLocalDateTimeConverter` seems fine : `new DateToLocalDateTimeConverter()`.

Now, if later you want to inject the `DateToLocalDateTimeConverter` instance in other Spring beans, it would make sense to transform it to a Spring Bean.

---

For information Spring provides already this utility task in the `Jsr310Converters` class (included in the spring-data-commons dependency) :

```
import static java.time.LocalDateTime.*;

public abstract class Jsr310Converters {
...
   public static enum DateToLocalDateTimeConverter implements Converter<Date, LocalDateTime> {

      INSTANCE;

      @Override
      public LocalDateTime convert(Date source) {
          return source == null ? null : ofInstant(source.toInstant(), ZoneId.systemDefault());
      }
  }
 ...
}
```

You could directly use it.

Comment: Thank you for comprehensive explanation. You mentioned that later it might make sense to transform it to a Spring Bean if circumstances require. How would you do that?

Comment: You are welcome :) As you did for  `conversionBean` : by declaring it in the Spring configuration and by referencing it in the  `conversionBean` declaration.

Comment: You were right to specify the import. I improve your edit by adding the static import as it is written in the original class.

Answer (score 1):

If you intend to inject this as a dependency of some kind into your application, and/or you intend to reuse it in multiple places, then it makes sense to register it as a bean.  If you're *not*, then `new`ing an instance up is acceptable.

Dependency injection and inversion of control are just that - how you inject dependencies into your app, and an acknowledgment that you no longer control how that's instantiated.  Should you desire either of these, beans are suitable; if you don't, then `new` it up.

Comment: ConversionService would be injected to other beans of the application, so beans can use it for conversion. Unfortunately from your answer I do not understand why it makes sense to register it as a bean, what is the benefit of being spring bean over just java object in such case. It is dependent object and it is not used anywhere in autonomy , except as dependency for `ConversionService`, which is Singleton itself. So it mean's it will be injected only single time per application lifetime. Please elaborate your point of view. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

In you simple case, it does not seem to be necessary to add `DateToLocalDateTimeConverter` as a spring bean.

Reasons to add `DateToLocalDateTimeConverter` as a spring bean:

- If it would make the implementation of `conversionService()` more readable (not the case in the question example)
- You need the `DateToLocalDateTimeConverter` in other beans
- The implementation of `DateToLocalDateTimeConverter` itself would need to have Spring beans injected, i.e. using `@Autowired`

Comment: Thank you for your reply, first two points are clear( although first point is arguable :) ).  Second point does make sense indeed.
Third point - does `DateToLocalDateTimeConverter` have to be Spring Bean to get other Spring bean injected and used by it?

Comment: I would say yes. To be able to inject into a java class, I would need to be managed by Spring. And adding it as a bean makes it spring managed. (I will try this out to be sure)

Comment: Just tried it and I confirm: `DateToLocalDateTimeConverter` itself can only have components injected by Spring if it is a spring Bean, also stated in the answer from Davidxxx